# Delete one of all duplicates that appear upto 2 times in MySQL Table column

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table of about 10,000 records there are duplicates in the titles some are repeated more than 5 times.

Sample Data

```
id| titleslug | views
--------------------
1 |the-box|  200
2 |the-box|  100
3 |the-box|   10
4 |the-man|   15
5 |the-man|   30
6 |the-cup|   10
7 |the-cup|   20
```

The box appears 3 times so I want to leave that but 'the-man' and 'the-cup' appears 2x I want to delete one of each of them so that the final table becomes

```
id| titleslug | views
--------------------
1 |the-box|  200
2 |the-box|  100
3 |the-box|   10
5 |the-man|   30
7 |the-cup|   20
```

If possible I will like to add the view count that is been deleted to the highest one that is been kept.

With the query below I was able to know the number of times items got duplicated.

```
select titleslug, count(*) as c from articles
group by titleslug having c > 1
order by c desc
```

I want to delete one of those  records that repeat only two times and leave the rest.
I am thinking of this query as below

```
 DELETE a
    FROM articles as a, articles as b
    WHERE
     (a.titleslug = b.titleslug OR a.titleslug IS NULL AND b.titleslug IS NULL)
      AND a.views < b.views;
```

But I need help to put the restriction to delete one only if  we have two duplicates.

I have used  the query below  which reports rows affected but after when I query it seems duplicates were not deleted

```
DELETE a
  FROM articles_copy a
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.Views) AS max_a1, t.TitleSlug
          FROM articles_copy t
      GROUP BY t.TitleSlug, t.Views
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND COUNT(*)<=2) b ON b.TitleSlug = a.TitleSlug
                              AND b.max_a1 > a.View
```

Comment: DELETE FROM table WHERE col1 IN (
    SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY id HAVING ( COUNT(col1) > 1 )
)

Comment: try group by titleslug  . let me know if this help . else please provide some sample data i will try to write query based on that

Comment: @YashveerSingh can you look at my query and advice why is not working

Comment: When I try your query:- DELETE FROM articles_copy WHERE TitleSlug IN ( SELECT TitleSlug FROM articles_copy GROUP BY TitleSlug HAVING ( COUNT(TitleSlug) > 1 AND COUNT(TitleSlug)<=5))  I get an error You can't specify target table 'articles_copy' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option can be (evaluate performance issues):

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
    ->   `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `title` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ->   `views` INT UNSIGNED
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `articles`
    ->   (`title`, `views`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('the-box', 200),
    ->   ('the-box', 100),
    ->   ('the-box', 10),
    ->   ('the-man', 15),
    ->   ('the-man', 30),
    ->   ('the-cup', 10),
    ->   ('the-cup', 20);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `title`,
    ->   `views`
    -> FROM
    ->   `articles`;
+----+---------+-------+
| id | title   | views |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | the-box |   200 |
|  2 | the-box |   100 |
|  3 | the-box |    10 |
|  4 | the-man |    15 |
|  5 | the-man |    30 |
|  6 | the-cup |    10 |
|  7 | the-cup |    20 |
+----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `articles`
    ->   INNER JOIN (
    ->     SELECT MAX(`id`) `id`, SUM(`views`) `views`
    ->     FROM `articles`
    ->     GROUP BY `title`
    ->     HAVING COUNT(`title`) = 2
    ->   ) `der`
    -> SET `articles`.`views` = `der`.`views`
    -> WHERE `articles`.`id` = `der`.`id`;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> DELETE FROM `articles`
    -> WHERE `id` IN (SELECT MIN(`der`.`id`)
    ->                FROM (SELECT `id`, `title`
    ->                      FROM `articles`) `der`
    ->                GROUP BY `der`.`title`
    ->                HAVING COUNT(`der`.`title`) = 2);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> COMMIT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `title`,
    ->   `views`
    -> FROM
    ->   `articles`;
+----+---------+-------+
| id | title   | views |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | the-box |   200 |
|  2 | the-box |   100 |
|  3 | the-box |    10 |
|  5 | the-man |    45 |
|  7 | the-cup |    30 |
+----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Great help with this you are a star

Comment: Your update query takes a longer time so I used DELETE a
  FROM articles_copy a
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.Views) AS max_a1, t.TitleSlug
          FROM articles_copy t
      GROUP BY t.TitleSlug
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND COUNT(*)<=2) b ON b.TitleSlug = a.TitleSlug AND b.max_a1 > a.View which took 1.335 seconds on 12K rows